# connection issue with gcp json key in airflow

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, airflow, service-accounts

I am using apache-airflow[google] v3.2.0. I started airflow. Created a simple dag which uses BigQueryInsertJobOperator to insert data in bigquery. Then from airflow UI, I navigated to Admin>Connections, connection Id as google_cloud_default, connection type as Google Cloud, and added key path, keyfile, project id. Then updated the dag task with parameter `gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default'`, While running the dag, I am getting following error:

```
ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usernme/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py", line 259, in get_credentials_and_project_id
    keyfile_dict_json = json.loads(keyfile_dict)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usernme/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 433, in _execute_task
    result = execute_callable(context=context, **execute_callable_kwargs)
  File "/home/usernme/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/bigquery.py", line 2795, in execute
    self.project_id = hook.project_id
  File "/home/usernme/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py", line 363, in project_id
    _, project_id = self.get_credentials_and_project_id()
  File "/home/usernme/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py", line 261, in get_credentials_and_project_id
    raise AirflowException("Invalid key JSON.")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid key JSON.
```

The same json key works perfectly fine when I use it directly on python code.